# Two div elements should stay in one row

Tags: html, css

I have a html page with 2 divs and they should resize, but always stay in one row. How can I build this?

I have the following example html code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <div id="table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>ONE</td>
      <td>TWO</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <p>This is a sidebar</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the style sheet looks like this:

```
#content {
  width: 100%;
}

#table {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 170px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using floats and the calc() function

Here is one way of doing it using floats and the `calc()` function (CSS3):

```css
#content {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  overflow: auto; /* useful for enclosing the floated region */
}
#table {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 170px); /* modern but not yet widely supported */
  background-color: red;
}
#table table {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 100%; /* '100%' for full-width; 'auto' for shrink-to-fit content */
}
#sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 170px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Float your `#table` and `#sidebar` to the left and right respectively.

When you float an element, its with will compute to a shrink-to-fit value unless you specify a width value.

If you specify `width: 100%` on `#table`, this will force the sidebar to start on a new line.

To allow space for the sidebar, use `calc(100% - 170px)` to computer the ideal maximum width for the table panel.

The `calc()` function is supported by the latest browsers, so this solution may not be suitable.

**[See Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/AnwwE/)**

Answer (score 1):

Change your content css to

```
#content {
width: 100%;
display:inline-block;
}
```

but here as your table width is set to 100% how the main div will accept 170px in the same line.

after #table goes beyond 81% it pushes the content to next line

Answer (score 0):

You are giving #content width of 100% so it will take whole space. You will need to adjust both div's width and float #content to left so that it calculates to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

```
Float:left;
```

for both divs and then put them in a wrap and then size the wrap to however you want it to look.

```
.wrap {

 width: 500px;
 height:800px;
}
```

So for your code, CSS:

```
#content {
  width: 100%;
}
#wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#table {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
#sidebar {
 width: 170px;
 background-color: blue;
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="content">
  <div id="table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>ONE</td>
      <td>TWO</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <p>This is a sidebar</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle...It helps to achieve what you need.

Here's updated css..

```
#content {
  width: 100%;
}

#table {
    float: left;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
  width: 170px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thx, but with this example the table doesn´t use the whole space. I also want, that sidebar and table fills the whole horizontal space.